# How to check if NLog writing to database

Tags: c#, .net, database, connection-string, nlog

In our application, we are using nlog for log management. We are writing the log in both text files and databases. In some cases, the log is getting written in the text file, but not in the database. I doubt it is due to some problem while setting the connection string dynamically. How can I debug that? Is there a way to write the sql queries and responses generated by NLog in a console? Also let me know if there is some work around for this.

Comment: ekanthike tamar badi kotho dur?

Comment: Is there any exception that is thrown? What happens when you debug your own code?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure nlog to do logging about nlog it self:

[NLog internal logging](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Internal_logging)

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
   <targets>
      <!-- target configuration here -->
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <!-- log routing rules -->
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

or have a look at:

[Logging not working, how to troubleshoot](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Logging_is_not_working_-_how_to_troubleshoot_it?)